# passing a link title to the next page

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make automatically generated pages for users based on the username. 
Basically I'm creating a table in HTML which displays all the users currently registered. The names are hyperlinks which redirect to a page in which I will post a welcome message.

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the name of the user I click on to the next page.

```
    <table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while($currentRow = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='/templates/profile.php?name='". $currentRow['name']  .">" . $currentRow['name'] . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $currentRow['email'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    ?>
```

As you can see, I tried using get, but it won't work, I think it's because it doesn't know what I'm clicking on. The point is that I want the page with the welcome message say something like "welcome, $username". Any ideas?

Comment: Your solution should work if profile.php reads $_GET['name']

Comment: Use `$_SESSION['store_link'] = 'YOUR LINK'`

Comment: yes, the problem was a little ' that was put incorrectly.. a really silly mistake, but I'm just learning php since a few days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have need remove single quote after ?name= and add it to before character >

Use

```
echo "<td><a href='/templates/profile.php?name=". $currentRow['name']  ."'>" .
$currentRow['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

Instead of

```
echo "<td><a href='/templates/profile.php?name='". $currentRow['name']  .">" .
$currentRow['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: it works. thanks a bunch. I will accept the answer when it lets me (7 mins).

Comment: Maybe add some URL encoding too?

Comment: yep, I will definitely do that too.

Answer (score 3):

You are closing the string with single quotes "'" that is why $_GET does not work. Replace profile.php?name='" with profile.php?name=" and also remove the single quote on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

try this in profile.php

```
Welcome <?php echo $_GET['name'];?>
```

Comment: I would consider adding escaping cause this is a possible XSS.

Answer (score 0):

In your `profile.php`

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: @icarus even its not getting name ?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><a href='/templates/profile.php?name=". $currentRow['name']  ."'>" . $currentRow['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

close the single code after name value you are sending in a tag..
thats it.